# Хочу узнать с помощью цикла в python'e есть ли совпадения в файле. txt?

Tags: python, python-3.x

У меня есть проблема. В файле есть очень много ссылок, и я хочу через цикл узнать есть ли одинаковые ссылки в файле **`.txt`**. Так как если будут одинаковые ссылки у меня будет ошибка в другом коде.

https://pastebin.com/9sbTu89C вот пример как я пытался решить эту проблему, но явно я написал что-то не то.

```
with open(r"manyurls.txt", "r") as file:
    for manyurls in file:
        if manyurls == manyurls:
            print(manyurls)
```

Comment: Для начала скажите, как хранятся ваши ссылки в файле? Сейчас вы считываете его построчно, и если у вас ссылки записаны в одну строку, то надо поступать иначе. Также стоит отметить, что сейчас вы делаете полную бессмыслицу - вы сравниваете текущую ссылку с собой же, а нужно сравнивать с предыдущими. Это же и является решением вашей проблемы: добавляйте каждую текущую ссылку в список или, что намного эффективнее, в set и на каждой итерации проверяйте, находится ли текущая ссылка среди всех предыдущих, сложенных в список/множество. Если входит, значит, она повторилась, и вам нужно ее вывести.

Comment: Но в этом решении есть небольшой недостаток: каждая уникальная ссылка будет выведена столько раз, сколько она повторится в файле - то есть, если ссылка повторилась четырежды, то три раза она будет выведена в консоль. В качестве решения предлагаю использовать collections.Counter(), загрузить в него список всех ссылок после их считывания, и далее вытащить из него все ссылки, которые повторились более одного раза: `counter = collections.Counter(list_urls); ans = [url for url in counter if counter[url] > 1]`

Answer (score 0):

Создал два списка , один - силок , второй(необязательный) - повторяющихся силок.

```
listOfUrls = []
listOfSecondUrls = []
with open(r"manyurls.txt", "r") as file:
    for url in file:
        if url not in listOfUrls:
            listOfUrls.append(url)
        else:
            listOfSecondUrls.append(url)
```